# iOS: Can I get the pitch/yaw/roll from accelerometer data?

Tags: ios, ipad, accelerometer

I want to find out the pitch, yaw, and roll on an iPad 1. Since there is no deviceMotion facility, can I get this data from the accelerometer? I assume that I can use the vector that it returns to compare against a reference vector i.e. gravity.

Does iOS detect when the device is still and then take that as the gravity vector? Or do I have to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid, without the gyroscope, you can not...iOS does not detect when the device is still because it can not detect speed, only acceleration.

Comment: So when it detects the 4 orientations it's looking for what? Seems to me that I could begin rotating about the z axis and then without accelerating continue rotating through all four orientations. If what you say is true, because it's not accelerating it would never know which way is up. I deduce therefore that it is detecting gravity, which is a constant acceleration, as a vector and this is how it ascertain which of the 4 orientations it is in.

Comment: exactly, if you hold it up straight, and rotate about z-axis, only the accelerations detected by x and y components will change which can be used to find angle with vertical. But you can not find vertical roll using accelerometer where a gyroscope can help you out

Answer (score 6):

It's definitely possible to calculate the Pitch and Roll from accelerometer data, but Yaw requires more information (gyroscope for sure but possibly compass could be made to work).

For an example look at [Hungry Shark for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hungry-shark-part-1/id383125988?mt=8) .  Based on how their [tilt calibration ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fTdF.jpg) works I'm pretty sure they're using the accelerometer instead of the gyroscope.

Also, here are some formula's I found on a [blog post from Taylor-Robotic](http://web.archive.org/web/20130725084409/http://taylor-robotic.co.uk/?p=64) a for calculating pitch and roll:

> Now that we have 3 outputs expressed in g we should be able to
>   calculate the pitch and the roll. This requires two further equations.
>
> ```
>  pitch = atan (x / sqrt(y^2 + z^2))
>  roll = atan (y / sqrt(x^2 + z^2))
> ```
>
> This will produce the pitch and roll in radians, to convert them into
>   friendly degrees we multiply by 180, then divide by PI.
>
> ```
>  pitch = (pitch * 180) / PI
>  roll = (roll * 180) / PI
> ```

The thing I'm still looking for is how to calibrate the pitch and roll values based on how the user is holding the device.  If I can't figure it out soon, I may open up a separate question.  Good Luck!

Comment: your links are basically broken.

Comment: @SpaceDog Taylor-Robotic no longer exists, so I updated the link to a copy on the Internet Archive